# breaking loops with a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-3.8

So I have this code:

```
def restart(x, y):
        if gameEnd == True:
            if x >= -78.0 and x <= 78.0 and y >= -52.0 and y <= 52.0:
                return True
screen.listen()
screen.onscreenclick(restart)

while True:
if restart():
            break
```

when i click a certain area i want it to break the loop

Comment: it can't be "and" mutually exclusive things.

Comment: You need to add more information. When does gameEnd become True for instance. What is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable outside of your while loop and set it to true, then when your condition `restart()` is met, set the variable to false. This will prevent the while loop body from executing.

Something like this would work:

```
var loop = True
while loop:
    if restart():
        loop = False
        break
```